# html page as a widget

Tags: javascript, html, widget

Let's say I have a widget that is like a simple interest calculator it is in a file index.html and it has a javascript part (with logic and style). The code uses javascript, html, bootstrap, ajax and chartjs.

How do I make it into a one line widget that i can copy and paste into my wordpress site ?
something like inside a div. So that I can copy a div and a link to script file and thus put my calculator on a page in multiple sites.

```
elements to embed is in a html file named-index.html
the html file is also on a site like someexamplesite.com/pages.html 
logic and style in a js file: simpleinterest.js
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an [iframe](https://www.w3schools.com/Tags/tag_iframe.asp) to embed your calculator on other sites like this:

```
<iframe src="https://someexamplesite.com/pages.html"></iframe>
```